# VSCode for macOSでArduinoの.inoをコンパイルする度にArduino IDEのロゴの窓が最前面に表れるのを止める方法

Tags: macos, vscode, arduino

VSCodeでArduinoを扱う最もメジャーな方法ではコンパイルするたびにArduino IDEのロゴが最前面に出てギョッとします．
ヘッドレスで起動するオプション，最背面で起動するテクニック，Arduino IDEを使わない代替ツールなどなんでもいいのでロゴを表示しない方法を教えてください．

Answer (score 0):

有料ですが、vMicroという、visual studioの拡張機能があります。
https://www.visualmicro.com/